# Mouse drag with CTRL selects/highlights elements

Tags: firefox, selection

I'm kinda new to Firefox (after switching from Opera due to making Chropera, bleh) and I find one functionality annoying - when I hold CTRL and drag mouse with LMB down page elements are selected/highlighted with blue borders. I have no idea what it is nor how to disable it, and it's in my way because I wanted to map to this combination SnapLinks addon (which I used under Opera with same combo). Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

*I'll test this in a moment*
could this tutorial help? http://www.websilt.com/blog/?p=139

And if you really want to configure hotkey's, maybe ahk is for you. Both might be overkill though.

If you can find your function, type about:config in the firefox url and disable it. That's probably the better way to do it.

Comment: Ok, Thank you for the answer but it kinda is not it :) I have found out that it's related `-moz-user-select: text !important;` :)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
actually this doesn't work but I'm leaving it here for reference.

OK, simple fix. Create a new file `Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\${profile_name}\chrome\userContent` and add there:

```
@-moz-document domain() {
-moz-user-select: text !important;
user-select: text !important;       
}
```